# Javascript what is wrong with my If statement?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this Javascript here and for some reason only the first if updates my div, even though the else if is almost identical? The else if should be triggering, can anyone help?

```
function giftDD(gift) {
  var dDV = document.getElementById(gift);
  if (garray[gift] > 0) {
    document.getElementById('giftMoney' + gift).remove();
    garray[gift]--;
  }

  var dDD = document.createElement('div');
  if (dDV.value == "Money") {
    alert(dDV.value);
    dDD.setAttribute('id', 'giftMoney' + gift);
    document.getElementById('gifttitle' + gift).innerHTML = "Gift: Money";
    dDD.innerHTML = "<div id='gift#" + gift + "'class='form-group'><div class='form-group'></div><div class='form-group' id='giftno" + gift + "'><div class='form-group'><input type='text' placeholder='£(pounds) e.g. 200' class='f1-gift form-control' name='gift" + gift + "' ng-pattern='/^[0-9]*$/'></input></div><div class='form-group'><input type='text' placeholder='Beneficiary Name...' class='f1-gift form-control' name='benef" + gift + "'></input></div><div class='form-group'><select type='text' class='form-control' name='condition" + gift + "'><div class='form-group'><option value='' selected hidden>Special Conditions...</option><option value='None'>None</option><option value='ReachedAge'>At The Age Of</option><option value='Marriage'>After Marriage</option></div><div class='form-group'></div></div></div>";
    document.getElementById("giftadd" + dDV.id).appendChild(dDD);
    garray[gift]++;
  } else if (dDV.Value === "Shares") {
    alert(dDV.value);
    dDD.setAttribute('id', 'giftShares' + gift);
    document.getElementById('gifttitle' + gift).innerHTML = "Gift: Shares";
    dDD.innerHTML = "<div id='gift#" + gift + "'class='form-group'><div class='form-group'></div><div class='form-group' id='giftno" + gift + "'><div class='form-group'><input type='text' placeholder='Amount of Shares' class='f1-gift form-control' name='gift" + gift + "' ng-pattern='/^[0-9]*$/'></input></div><div class='form-group'><input type='text' placeholder='Beneficiary Name...' class='f1-gift form-control' name='benef" + gift + "'></input></div><div class='form-group'><select type='text' class='form-control' name='condition" + gift + "'><div class='form-group'><option value='' selected hidden>Special Conditions...</option><option value='None'>None</option><option value='ReachedAge'>At The Age Of</option><option value='Marriage'>After Marriage</option></div><div class='form-group'></div></div></div>";
    document.getElementById("giftadd" + dDV.id).appendChild(dDD);
    garray[gift]++;
  }
  alert(dDV.value);
}
```

Comment: may be Value is not value

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive. The first case is right: `dDV.value`. The second case is wrong: `dDV.Value`.

Comment: Javascript is case-sensitive. You should check `value` not `Value` in the `else`

Comment: if the first if block matches then it doesn't keep flowing through the block.

Comment: One time you write `value` and the other time `Value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second if statement has an error.

```
dDV.Value
```

Should be

```
dDV.value
```

JavaScript is case sensitive.

Comment: Questions with typographical errors should be marked as that and not answered.

Comment: And you can still help them learn through the comments. You can still help people learn without misusing the site.

Comment: @MikeC: If these questions shouldn't be answered, then they should be questions at all. Why hasn't it been deleted?

Comment: @musefan Because someone wrote an answer with at least one upvote so it's no longer a candidate for deletion. Had this answer *not* been posted, this question would have been deleted.